# WireGuard error

Tags: networking, server, vpn, wireguard

I'm trying to use WireGuard to configure a VPN tunnel *via* my server, and up to now it worked perfectly. However, I changed server, pasted my old config files (just changing the private and public keys newly generated) all according to [this tutorial](https://www.ckn.io/blog/2017/11/14/wireguard-vpn-typical-setup/), and now when I activate `wg0-client` on my machine, I get:

```
[#] ip link add wg0-client type wireguard
[#] wg setconf wg0-client /dev/fd/63
[#] ip address add 10.200.200.2/32 dev wg0-client
[#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg0-client
[#] resolvconf -a tun.wg0-client -m 0 -x
Too few arguments.
Too few arguments.
[#] wg set wg0-client fwmark 51820
[#] ip -4 route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev wg0-client table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add not fwmark 51820 table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
```

... and I can't connect to the Internet!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: that guide doesn't have you simply copy each file first, like `cp /etc/sysctl.conf /etc/sysctl.conf.bak`. this is something you should add yourself to each step even if guides don't say to do so. this way you can both revert to working case in case of errors and work out where the error is. ....The message you got says two few arguments. that means in your configuration you have two sets of arguments that are one or more arguments short. ...Do you know what arduments are?

Comment: No, I don't kwno what arguments are

Comment: ok arguments are the words or numbers you'll pass to the executable. like for example your program is "makeUsBreakfast" you call it like this `makeUsBreakfast (for 5 people) (at 10:00) (blueberry waffles)` and in reality arguments are implicit so it would actually be `makeUsBreakfast 5 10 BBW` and the program would understand that because it always expect the first argument it gets, to be a number or people, the second, to be an hour of the day and the last to be a code for it's recipes. If you say `makeUsBreakfast 5` then it will fail with the error message `Too few arguments.` like you have.